# How to print a variable name in a print statement or any text output statement. Python, Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Here is the code for correlation from a dataset

```
x = df["var1"]
y = df["var2"]

cor = x.corr(y)

print(f"The Correlation between x and y is: %1.2f"%cor )
```

Output would be:

*The Correlation between x and y is: -0.22*

I would like the output to be:

*The Correlation between var1 and var2 is: -0.22*

Reason being those variable will be constantly changing, I don't want to manually change those when I need to. What can I try next?

Comment: Hi there. Please do not add voting commentary in your question. It's not mandatory to tick/check/accept answers, but it is nice to do so. If you want to add a comment under an answer to say that you feel both were correct, that is also fine. Just let the question remain a question, since it is asked before answer come in.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using f-strings, I would make the dataframe column headers variables, so the print statement is updated each time:

```
x_col = "var1"
y_col = "var2"

x = df[x_col]
y = df[y_col]

cor = x.corr(y)

print(f"The Correlation between {x_col} and {y_col} is: {cor:1.2f}" )
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to print variables in string. You can do following code:

```
print("The Correlation between "+x+" and "+y+" is: %1.2f"%cor )
```

or

```
print("The Correlation between {} and {} is: {}".format(x,y,cor))
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Just use equal sign in your format

```
cor = x.corr(y)
print(f'{cor=:1.2f}')
```